# $.each called twice in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, each

The following code works but it get called twice, that is assets.length display the correct length, then it gets called again and display twice the length.

Any idea? Thanks.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://192.168.1.1/rest/Address?format=json' , 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) { 

        $.each(data, function() {

            $.each(this, function(i, subelement) {

                if (subelement) {

                    assets.push({id:subelement.Id,
                        stnumber:subelement.StreetNumber,
                        stname:subelement.StreetName,
                        sttype:subelement.StreetType,
                        }); 
                }
            });

        });
        console.log ("assets.length =>"+assets.length);
     }
```

});

Comment: It seems like the code that calls `$.ajax` is running twice

Comment: Could you please attach your json result?

Comment: You are sending ajax request twice. Check your code.

Comment: `async: false` is very bad for user experience.  Browser will appear to lock up during the ajax call.  Much better to use `async` and adapt your programming to work with `async`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that I am can't see the wood for the trees. $.ajax is being called twice. Thanks Explosion Pills/pvnarula.